# How to get the rest response code of golang docker client on starting a container?

Tags: docker, go, containers, docker-api

When I do

```
curl -X POST -v --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://docker/containers/container_name/start
```

I got response codes like 204, 304, 404, 502

How to get the same response codes from the golang docker client? As of now, startcontainer function in golang is only returning an error string

dockerclient function:

```
ContainerStart(ctx context.Context, containerID string, options dockTypes.ContainerStartOptions) error
```

Comment: Unfortunately you're not going to get the response codes, the Moby client only ensures the response object is closed, and does not return it. You can check it out here: https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/client/container_start.go#L11

Comment: Got it....thank you :)